# Rating bar not shown 5th start proper in navigation view

Tags: java, android, ratingbar

[Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD7uu.jpg)
[I have add rating bar in navigation view in drawer layout but it is not show 5th start properly in design]

```
   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NavigationView"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorWhite"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary1"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
    android:scrollIndicators="none">



    <include
        android:id="@+id/premium_footer"
        layout="@layout/navigation"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/thirty_dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Post full code related to issue.